# TypeError: <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f81898af438> is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, python-3.5, boto3, amazon-polly

I am trying to create an *AWS Lambda* function using Python, which shall receive a text from some API and return a JSON containing `AudioStream` object. For this I am using *AWS Polly*. Currently I am able to get the `AudioStream` from AWS on my machine and it is working fine.

For using  AWS Polly I have created a special user and given him `AmazonPollyReadOnlyAccess` and `AmazonPollyFullAccess` access.

```
import boto3,json

polly= boto3.client('polly')
text='<speak>hey there wassup </speak>'

spoken_text=polly.synthesize_speech(Text=text,OutputFormat='mp3',VoiceId='Aditi',TextType='ssml')

newdata=json.dumps(spoken_text)
# return newdata
print(type(spoken_text))
```

But when I am trying to use this code snippet to return the response in JSON format I am getting the error.

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /talker/aditi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/talker/aditi.py", line 9, in <module>
    newdata=json.dumps(spoken_text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f81898af438> is not JSON serializable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Answer (score 7):

Parse the response from the client first before dumping or returning it.

For example:

```
response = spoken_text['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
return response
```

Comment: This worked for me while working with lambda invocation, but with the caveat that I switched 'Body' to 'Payload'

Comment: That is the solution indeed to the problem, also saved me a lot of time

Answer (score -3):

You need to pass it using below function:

```
newdata=bytes(json.dumps(spoken_text))
```

and when you want to read the returned value, you need to use the below method:

```
print(returned_value.read())
```